# file_get_contents - Connection timed out

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
echo $
```

Why is the browser returning this error?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.google.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/test.php on line 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Mostly probably your server cannot connect to an external resource, for example, because of firewall restrictions.

Comment: ...or Google is down, but that didn't seem likely :D

Comment: Btw, I used google just for example, it's working, but with the link I want isn't.

Comment: Oh, well what happens if you hit the link with your browser?

Comment: care to share a URI that doesn't work for us to replicate the error with?

Comment: I'm trying with this: http://www.neobux.com/rel/bl/?o=F298ABD1FF98A0085487B0A8449F83BD

Comment: First time here at stackoverflow.. are you still there?

Comment: No sure - if it works for Google.com but not that address then perhaps they're blocking requests by user agent, IP or something. Not really enough information provided I'm afraid.

Comment: Call your ISP and ask them.  That's the easiest way.  @Hamish is right, this is likely a firewall issue.  Many ISPs don't allow these sorts of connections.

Comment: Call Google admins and order them to bring Google up :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, couldn't download using file_get_contents(), but using curl on the command line for the same URL worked fine. Turned out it tried to connect over IPv6 which failed.

I solved it by disabling IPv6 in my kernel parameters.

Comment: Rather than turning off IPv6, you should try to fix it. You can also make [`file_get_contents()` try connection over IPv6 and then also over IPv4](https://www.slightfuture.com/webdev/php-file-contents-dual-stack) if that fails.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents` does not work well at all with getting remote files and should not be used. It does not deal with slow network connections or redirects, and does not return error codes. You should use `curl` instead to fetch remote files.

There is an example in the manual for `curl_exec`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: I assure you that file_get_contents() works just fine with getting remote files, and *can* be used in *most* situations.  Also, it *does* follow proper HTTP redirects, but there have been bugs reported recently with this feature, which I am assuming is what you are referring to.  Finally, yes, if you need the HTTP status codes then you should use something more robust.  If you simply need to catch an error then you can use file_get_contents() just fine.  Again, this is fine for plenty of situations, but certainly not all, as you have pointed out.

Comment: Down voting a correct answer? I didn't say it didn't work, I said it doesn't work well. curl is a much more reliable and robust tool to use, as you stated. The timeout error experienced most likely would not happen with curl since curl defaults to the network timeout (i.e. 2 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

It might be server side issue, might be your server cannot communicate with other server remotely. You have to communicate with server administrator.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason **file_get_contents()** fails intermittently on some websites that support IPv6 (maybe 20% of the time, the command times-out).  Although disabling IPv6 resolves the issue, that is not the best solution as more sites move to IPv6.

I wrote a simple PHP **gethtml(**) function that works around the issue using **wget**.  This will automatically use IPv6 when IPv4 is not available.  A minor drawback is that it uses an external command, but I think it is preferable to disabling IPv6.

If **wget** is not already installed on your distribution, you can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt install wget
```

PHP Function Example:

```
$myhtml = gethtml("http://example.com");

//use instead of file_get_contents() due to inconsistent IPv6 performance
function gethtml($url){return shell_exec("wget --prefer-family=IPv4 -qO- ".$url);}
```