# PHP can't access internet

Tags: php, curl, networking

This works perfectly

```
curl http://google.com
```

This doesn't:

```
php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```

I am getting the warning:

```
PHP Warning: file_get_contents(google.com): failed to open stream: Connection timed out"
```

but then if I do something like

```
php -r "echo file_get_contents('http://localhost:8000');
```

on a local server it works, somehow I must have messed something in the php configuration, can anyone one have a clue to solve this?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? We can't help you with "this doesn't work"

Comment: Here is an answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

Comment: Yes sorry, I am getting the typical "PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://google.com): failed to open stream: Connection timed out"

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189973/file-get-contents-connection-timed-out

Comment: Yes @k0pernikus you're right, file_get_contents is not suited for this purpose I usually would use guzzle but I was lazy, I changed it to classical curl_int() ... and worked, my internet connection seems to be messed up.

Comment: @user3377450 I editted your question. Please use the formatting option to the codebase. Instead of posting code in the comments, edit your question. And finally, keep the question short and to the point.